# Laravel: How does the query builder handle ->first()?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

How does the query builder handle `->first()`?

Does it simply do a `Limit 1` or does it do some advanced checking to make sure if only 1 row is returned?

In rare cases, the application may want to ensure that ONLY 1 row will be returned. Perhaps `->first()` is not the best solution?

Any insight or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `first()`, `take(1)` and `limit(1)` do the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew Not true. `take` and `limit` only add a `LIMIT` clause to the query while first also executes the result and directly returns one object.

Comment: Ah, well, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `first()` method will always return one result or `null` if no results are found. Here's all it does:

```
public function first($columns = array('*'))
{
    $results = $this->take(1)->get($columns);

    return count($results) > 0 ? reset($results) : null;
}
```

The difference to just using `take(1)` (or `limit(1)`) is that it actually just returns one result object, by calling `reset()`. (Also, `first()` obviously executes the query. The others don't)